# Replace locale name in url using regex only(no string last index of)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have url scheme setup with following structure
www.foo.com/**bar**

For choosing locale specific page (bar), user can select different values from dropdown which will append locale code to the url like:

www.foo.com/en/**bar**

www.foo.com/za/**bar**

How can I use regex to replace url value before bar to include correct locale? I have following replacement that partially works but keeps on appending locale code multiple times if i keep on selecting diff vale as in:

www.foo.com/za/bar

www.foo.com/za/en/bar

```
string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
string url = Regex.Replace(referer, Request.Host.ToString(), $"{Request.Host.ToString()}/{lang}");
return Redirect(url);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? some websites follow language-region convention like `en-US`.

Comment: @Prajwal yes i have specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working using

```
string url = Regex.Replace(referer, @".*\/", $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.ToString()}/{lang}/");
```